# how to end the input sequence of characters: ASM: Int 21h function 01h

Tags: assembly, tasm

New to assembly.. this is the code. it reads sequence of characters and ends when you press enter

but the sequence of input characters has no limit when entered.. how to limit number of characters? for example i can only type 20 characters and the program will end?

and what does `AL` in `CMP` represent, and why `0DH`? i am confused in that line (`CMP AL,0DH`)

```
MAIN PROC

;INITIALIZE DS
MOV AX,@DATA     
MOV DS,AX

MOV     DI,1000H
MOV     AH,01H
LOOP:
INT     21H
CMP     AL,0DH
JE      END
MOV     [DI],AL
INC     DI
JMP     LOOP

END:
MOV AH,4CH         ;DOS EXIT FUNCTION
INT 21H            ;EXECUTE

MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: I think you're using the DOS read-character function, so just count a loop counter up to 20, or down from 20 to 0 as your loop-exit condition.  `cmp al, 0dH` compares the character you just read to see if it's a `\r`.  (DOS `ah=1 / int 21` returns the character in the `al` register).  See [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for more.

Comment: How am i going to  do this _"so just count a loop counter up to 20, or down from 20 to 0 as your loop-exit condition"_ sir @PeterCordes

Comment: Every loop iteration gets one character, right?  So instead of an infinite loop, make it a loop that runs at most 20 iterations.  e.g. `mov cx, 20` outside the loop.  Then use `dec cx / jnz LOOP` instead of `jmp LOOP`.  What other programming languages do you know?  Think about what needs to happen before you get caught up in the details of doing each step in asm.

Comment: newbie at programming, im an out student from other engineering course this is my first sem in programming language blabla and i took assembly and c++ this sem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prg reads the chars one by one, storing it at Adress 1000 and following. it obviously doesnt care for the input's length, and stops as soon as 0x0d is read (which is a newline, so it reads until enter is pressed)

( I replaced "mov [di],al" + "inc di" with "stosb" which does exactly the same thing )

to add a "max length" check, you could do something like this inside the loop:

```
mov ax, DI
sub ax, 0x1000
cmp ax, <the max length you want to read>
jae END
```

Note: the enter is not saved, so if you change SI (that currently points to the last char entered), will have a problem determining the string's end.
Better store the 0x0d too (or even better a 0x00), to have a end-of-string marker:

```
MAIN PROC

;INITIALIZE DS
MOV AX,@DATA     
MOV DS,AX
cld                 ; tell "stosb" to forward

MOV     DI,1000H    ; address where to string will be copied to
MOV     AH,01H      ; int 21 function 1: read char with echo
LOOP:
   INT     21H         ; read a char from keyboard
   stosb               ; store char in string
   CMP     AL,0DH      ; stop if enter is pressed (after storing, so 0x0d will be stored too)
JNE     LOOP

END:
MOV AH,4CH         ;DOS EXIT FUNCTION
INT 21H            ;EXECUTE

MAIN ENDP
```

or storing a 0x00 and input's end:

```
MAIN PROC

;INITIALIZE DS
MOV AX,@DATA     
MOV DS,AX
cld                 ; tell "stosb" to forward

MOV     DI,1000H    ; address where to string will be copied to
MOV     AH,01H      ; int 21 function 1: read char with echo
LOOP:
   INT     21H         ; read a char from keyboard
   CMP     AL,0DH      ; stop if enter is pressed
   JE      END
   stosb               ; save al at DI and increase DI by one
JMP     LOOP

END:
mov [di], 0         ; terminate string (instead of 0x0d)
MOV AH,4CH         ;DOS EXIT FUNCTION
INT 21H            ;EXECUTE

MAIN ENDP
```

One more idea on "limit the amount of chars read" (Instead of checking DI for 0x1000+20 to jump out of the read-loop) would be to use CX as counter and `loop` (loop is a conditional jump that decreases CX and jumps if CX didn't reach 0):

```
MAIN PROC

;INITIALIZE DS
MOV AX,@DATA     
MOV DS,AX
cld                 ; tell "stosb" to forward

mov     cx, 20      ; make sure to maximum read 20 chars
MOV     DI,1000H    ; address where to string will be copied to
MOV     AH,01H      ; int 21 function 1: read char with echo
LOOP:
   INT     21H         ; read a char from keyboard
   CMP     AL,0DH      ; stop if enter is pressed
   JE      END
   stosb               ; save al at DI and increase DI by one
loop     LOOP

END:
mov [di], 0         ; terminate string (instead of 0x0d)
MOV AH,4CH         ;DOS EXIT FUNCTION
INT 21H            ;EXECUTE

MAIN ENDP
```

Comment: but the sequence of input characters has no limit when entered how to limit characters entered? for example i can only type 20 characters and the program will end?

Comment: usually you don't just write the string "somewhere" (like here to 0x1000), but you define a buffer for it. how to limit the read is written in the answer

Comment: `stosb` isn't clearly "better", unless you're optimizing for code size.  Especially for a beginner, learning to move pointers around and dereference them the general way is a good idea.  (performance-wise: `stos` is 3 uops on SnB-family, and apparently can't micro-fuse the store-address and store-data uops.  `inc` is 1 uop, and `mov [di], al` is also 1 uop (micro-fused store-address and store-data).)

Comment: Also, you should just `cmp di, 0x1000 + length_you_want_to_read`, instead of clobbering `ax`.  (especially since then you need to reset `ah=01H` for the next `int 21`)

Comment: yes, i thought about that, and i also thought about using BX instead for the calculation. I didn't change either ( the first is a question of flavour, and i personally prefer to compare length instead of base-pointer+length, but that's just flavour. And I left AX inside the compare, because assembler coding often includes "copy and paste snipets from somewhere", and clobbering is a trap better learned early ;)

Comment: oh - and I didnt say stosb is better ... it just does the same and it's shorter code, so why not use it here? that's exactly what it's made for. Even (especially?) beginners should try to use everything an instruction set offers. imo

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the DOS read-character function, so just count a loop counter up to 20, or down from 20 to 0 as your loop-exit condition. cmp al, 0dH compares the character you just read to see if it's a \r. (DOS ah=1 / int 21 returns the character in the al register). See the x86 tag wiki for more. – Peter Cordes.

```
    10qu Peter Cordes. have done it here and works perfectly!
```

Comment: Every loop iteration gets one character, right? So instead of an infinite loop, make it a loop that runs at most 20 iterations. e.g. mov cx, 20 outside the loop. Then use dec cx / jnz LOOP instead of jmp LOOP. What other programming languages do you know? Think about what needs to happen before you get caught up in the details of doing each step in asm. – Peter Cordes . 10qu Peter Cordes. have done it here and works perfectly!